# Implicit type conversion of anonymous object

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I try to convert to float anonymous object of class that have float implicit converter. I'm not sure if I explain it correctly. Here is example:

I have following class:

```
public class MyFloat 
{        
    public float Value { get; set; }

    public MyFloat(float val)
    {
        Value = val;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyFloat(float v) 
    {
        return new MyFloat(v);
    }

    public static implicit operator float(MyFloat d) 
    {
        return d.Value;
    }
```

Then if I try to:

```
object f1 = new MyFloat(5.0f);
float f2 = f1; // Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
float f3 = (MyFloat)f1;
```

I get InvalidCastException. I assume that f1 is treated as object and it's not checked if it's real type (MyFloat) have implicit to float converter.
Is there any way to workaround this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does that second line even compile? It doesn't look like it should...

Comment: Also note that "anonymous object" isn't a meaningful term. I don't know what you mean by that at all...

Comment: @MrFox But then, the float operator definition is meaningless.

Comment: Also, I think it would make better sense to not have the public property at all (given you expect `MyFloat` to be treated as `float`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, like you say, `f1` is treated as `object`, not `MyFloat` - you need to cast it from `object` back to `MyFloat` and then the implicit cast will work (like your second example).

Alternatively, don't declare it as `object` to start with and use it's real type - `MyFloat`.

Comment: @jyparask Yes, it would. var infers the variable type.

Comment: @jyparask yep, however, `var` is just a shorter way of saying "*use the real type here*".

Comment: But then it wouldn't be `object` any more, it would be `MyFloat f1 = new Myfloat(5.0f);`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen nope it wouldn't, however, from the example given I am struggling to see why it needs to be `object` to start with. It could of course be coming from some external system or *has* to be `object` for some other reason but that has yet to be clarified.

Comment: @James it's correct. It has to be object. Sorry for not clarified it before.

Comment: Well, then you need to cast it to `MyFloat` first. You could of course wrap it into a `dynamic`, and let the runtime figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `object` but `MyFloat`, otherwise the compiler does not know at compile time that your `object` is of type  `MyFloat`:

Instead of:

```
object f1 = new MyFloat(5.0f);
float f2 = f1; // Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not
```

this:

```
MyFloat f1 = new MyFloat(5.0f);
float f2 = f1;
```

or cast it accordingly (although that seems to be redundant):

```
float f2 = (MyFloat)f1
```